# Access res.locals in Multer.diskStorage->filename

Tags: node.js, express, postman, multer, dio

I'm working on a login, where the use consists of userImage, userName, userStatus (all send as form-data).
To upload the userImage im using Multer.
This is how my route looks like

`router.post('/create', upload.any(), createUser, upload.single('userImage'));`

`upload.any()` This im calling so that I can retrieve the userName & userStatus from the form-data body, which can't be accessed via `req.body` otherwise

`createUser` Is my middleware to create the User which looks like this

```
        var savedUser = await user.save();
        var createdUserId = savedUser._id;  // use this to add to the profile Image's name 

        var imgExtension = path.extname(req.body.userImage)
        var imgPath = `./images/profileImages/${createdUserId}_profileImage${imgExtension}`
        
        //now update the newly created user with its image 
        await userModel.updateOne({_id: createdUserId},{
            image: {
                path: imgPath,
                contentType: `image/${imgExtension}`  
            }
        });
        // to use in Multer middleware
        res.locals.imgName = String(`${createdUserId}_profileImage${imgExtension}`)

        res.status(201).json({
            message: "User has been saved",
            userId: createdUserId
        });        
        
        next()
```

So Im using mongoDB, after creating the user in the Database Im getting the ObjectID which I want to be included in the image name, only the path to the image is being saved on the server.

Now I'm trying to pass the imgName as `res.locals.imgName` to the Multer middleware so that I can store it on the server.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) =>{
        cb(null, './images/profileImages')
    },
    filename: (req , file, cb) => {
        const imgName = req.res.locals.imgName // HERE LIES THE PROBLEM
        cb(null, `${imgName}`)
    }
});
export var upload = multer({ storage: storage});
```

[if there is a typo in the code that I missed it's only because I couldn't copy and paste it to the Stackoverflow code-field, nodejs needs ` <- this symbol so that it can access variables in a String ]

So on the Database everything works out fine, all the information is saved correctly.

Now the Image is being saved on the server but as undefined, if I add a .png after the undefined I can also view the image.

I need a way to access the `res.locals.imgName` variable in Multer filename.
[Here I found something similar](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/620)

one user said `res.locals.something` can be accessed via `req.res`, he didn't say anything else so I tried every combination of `req.res.res.locals.imgName` to `req.res.imgName` and it's always undefined or doesn't work altogether.

So is there a way to solve this or do I have to MacGyver some workaround.

Answer (score 1):

`req.res.locals` works for me

```
const profilePicStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './user-profile-pictures/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, req.res.locals.authenticatedUserId)
    }
})
```